# Python и Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

Пишу небольшой проектик для себя. В нем я использую Postgresql(psycorg2). При попытке добавить вещественные число в базу, оно округляется до первых шести знаков. Пример:

```
12345678.12345 - > 12345700.0.
```

Перепробовал все типы: `real`, `numeric`, `double desision`, явно указывал точность, удалял бд и заново создавал. Числа как округлялись, так и продолжают округляться. Может кто-нибудь уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Заранее спасибо!

Таблицу создаю так:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (name TEXT NOT NULL, text TEXT NOT NULL, time REAL)").
```

Добавляю запись:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO messages (name, text, time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", ("Pavel", "Hello", 12345678.12345))
```

В базе оказывается

```
name: pavel, 
text: Hello, 
time: 12345700.0
```

Мне важна точность, а число почему-то сокращается

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы без __явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: а если в лоб - `text`?

Comment: Таблицу создаю: cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (name TEXT NOT NULL, text TEXT NOT NULL, time REAL)"). Добавляю запись: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO messages (name, text, time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", ("Pavel", "Hello", 12345678.12345)) В базе оказывается name: pavel, text: Hello, time: 12345700.0  Мне важна точность, а число почему-то сокращается

Comment: @pdavidchik Я добавил ваш комментарий и код в текст вопроса, можете комментарий удалить, он больше не нужен. Такие добавления лучше сразу в текст вопроса добавлять редактированием.

Answer (score 1):

У real точность 6 десятичных знаков, что и наблюдаете.

Пробуйте другие числовые типы - `decimal` или `double precision`.

Не работает с другими типами, вероятно, потому, что вы не удалили вручную таблицу. А ваш код ее не пересоздает, если она уже есть и тип у вас остался от самого первого создания таблицы, т.е. `real`. Проверить типы полей в таблице можно в psql командой `\d messages`.